# 100% width Featured Image Size

Tags: themes, post-thumbnails

I have looked all over the place for an answer and I cannot seem to find anything of relevance so I thought maybe someone here could provide some insight.

I want to use the featured image of a post or page as the background for the title area of the post/page similar to this http://viaforge.com/news/importance-of-being-a-mobile-first-agency/

I know how to get it done, thats not the problem. My problem is I want to add a 100% width and (pixelsize) height usng `add_image_size();` image size in functions.php.

Anyway of doing this? ANy help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

*yes I looked at all of the "Questions that may already have your answer" that popped up and none of them had an appropriate answer...lol or

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ack, nevermind I just discovered that using `get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'full' );           // Original resolution`

will use the width and height of the featured image.

I do apologize for wasting everyone's time. I should have been a little more patient ;)